# Tensorflow Eager False Postive/Negative Etc Rate

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have eager execution enabled and wasnt sure how to find specificity values or false postive etc values from my test or training data

```
test_dataset = tf.data.TextLineDataset(fileid + "test")
test_dataset = test_dataset.map(parse_csv)
test_dataset = test_dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=1000)
test_dataset = test_dataset.batch(32)

test_accuracy = tfe.metrics.Accuracy()

for (x, y) in test_dataset:
  prediction = tf.argmax(model(x), axis=1, output_type=tf.int32)
  test_accuracy(prediction, y)
```

Here is the code and i have determined accuracy but it is 90 percent due to my test data so need another way to analyse data

Comment: Please edit your question by adding a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that others can understand what _exactly_ went wrong with your code. As it stands, there is not enough information for us to work with.

Comment: Also, please, write a descriptive title for your post! What the heck does "Tensorflow Eager FP etc rate" mean?

Answer (score 0):

figured out a way to do it

```
truepositive = 0
falsepositive = 0
truenegative = 0
falsenegative = 0

y = y.numpy()
prediction = prediction.numpy()
for index in range(0,116):

  if prediction[index] ==1 and prediction[index] ==y[index]:
      truepositive = truepositive + 1
  if prediction[index] ==0 and prediction[index] ==y[index]:
      truenegative = truenegative + 1
  if prediction[index] ==0 and prediction[index] !=y[index]:
      falsenegative = falsenegative + 1  
  if prediction[index] ==1 and prediction[index] !=y[index]:
      falsepositive = falsepositive + 1  

print("sensitivity" + str(truepositive/(truepositive+falsenegative)))
print("specificity" + str(truenegative/(truenegative+falsepositive)) )
```